# Can't import GoogleCloudMessaging from Cocoapods in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

My problem is that I can't import GoogleCloudMessaging, downloaded by podfile, to my Swift project.
My steps:

1. I installed it by 
   pod 'GoogleCloudMessaging', '~> 1.2'
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3rKm.png

2.It has not ".framework", but ".a" file library. So I added this to my Linked Frameworks and Libraries:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cImxW.png

3. Also I imported it to my bridging-Header and all is ok, I did not see any errors. Looks like:

```
#import <GoogleCloudMessaging/GoogleCloudMessaging.h>
```

4. So I tried to add library to my AppDelegate with:

   import GoogleCloudMessaging

   But it shows error **"No such module 'GoogleClougMessaging'"**

I read some posts about such problem with Google Frameworks, tried to set (changed Google to GoogleCloudMessaging):

"So Instead of adding $(SRCROOT)/Pods (recursive) I added:
"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Google" (recursive) to the Header Search Paths
"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Google" (recursive) to the Framework Search Paths"

But it did not help.

P.S.: sorry, I have not enough reputation to display images in post, so i added links to screenshots

**EDIT**
God, I did it.
Don't know why, but trying to 'pod Google/CloudMessaging' causes error "Specs satisfying the `Google/CloudMessaging` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.". But it was 8.0, so this is strange.
Finally I just download my project from my repo with "git clone ..." to new folder and then did "pod install", and all works fine, my 'pod Google/CloudMessaging' was installed successfully. The error with importing dissapeared, and I don't even need to put this library to Linked Frameworks and Libraries, and did not write any import to AppDelegate

Comment: I want to, but my back-end server said that he can't implement it

Comment: ok can you show your pod file content

Comment: yes, here is link (it has "use_frameworks!") http://clip2net.com/clip/m496854/f5777-clip-57kb.png?nocache=1

Comment: bridge header must be specified incorrectly. please show how you set its path and also where the file resides

Comment: Other libraries work with it. Link: http://clip2net.com/clip/m496854/a9022-clip-341kb.png?nocache=1

Comment: try changing pod to `pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'` and then import line to `#import <Google/CloudMessaging.h>`

Comment: Pod didn't see Google/CloudMessaging, after typing "pod install" it shows error (think it is old version):   " [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Google/CloudMessaging` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `Google/CloudMessaging` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target."

Comment: it worked for me. had 8.0 target. can you try testing in a new simple project ?

Comment: Done. In another projects works fine with "pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'". What problem can be in my project? Have not any idea :(

Comment: Shubhank, thank you for help, now it's work.